# Image Rotator using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Im tryin to create an image rotator where an image will change every 3 seconds.But the problem is, images aren't showing up. Here is my code:

```
    <html>


<script type='text/javascript'>

    var myScreen=document.getElementById("banner");
    var pictures=['stephIrv.jpg','pintball.jpg','badminton.jpg','running.jpg','boxing.jpg'];
    var ttlPics = pictures.length;
    var i=0;
    function slideShow()
    {
        if(i > (ttlPics - 1))
        {
            i=0;
        }
        myScreen.innerHTML = '<img src="'+pictures[i]+'">';
        i++;
        loopTimer = setTimeout(slideShow,3000);
    }
    slideShow();
</script>
<body>

<div id = 'banner'></div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The first argument in `setTimeout` has to be a variable not a string. You don't have a `loop` function declared anywhere either.

Comment: Tried it but still not working :c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pictures need to be inside the same folder, as your script. But I guess you have that already.

First thing I would change, is to use `slideShow` in `setTimeout` instead of `'loop()'`?

```
loopTimer = setTimeout(slideShow, 3000);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: You are using ``'slideShow()'`` in ``setTimeout`` as first parameter, try changing that to ``slideShow`` without the single-quotes and without the ``()``. Just as I suggested in my answer. You need to use a callback here, not a string.

Comment: Can you share, what is happening, please? Are there any error-messages in your browser-console? What is missing?

Comment: There are no error message appearing in my browser. When I run my code, the browser is just a blank white space. No images are appearing.

Comment: UPDATE! I got it working by putting the entire <script> tag in the <body> after the <div>. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Okay. When testing it, I actually did the same, but missed the point. Congrats!

Comment: Thanks for your help!